# building apache thrift 0.9 on ubuntu libthrift.so not found

Tags: ubuntu, build, thrift

I am trying to build thrift 0.9 on Ubuntu 13.04 using create-debian-packages.sh.

First I had some problem with mongel dependency, it wasn't in a repository.
So I installed mongrel with gem install and removed dependency from contol file to make it build packages. Got not errors and here are the packages I got.

```
thrift-compiler_0.9.0_amd64.deb
libthrift0_0.9.0_amd64.deb
libthrift-cil_0.9.0_all.deb
libthrift-dev_0.9.0_amd64.deb
libthrift-java_0.9.0_all.deb
libthrift-perl_0.9.0_all.deb
php5-thrift_0.9.0_amd64.deb
python-thrift_0.9.0_amd64.deb
python-thrift-dbg_0.9.0_amd64.deb
ruby-thrift_0.9.0_all.deb
```

After installing them all, except libthrift-cil_0.9.0_all.deb, I cant find shared library libthrift.so. Static link library libthrift.a does exist.

What could be the problem? How can I get it built and installed?

Comment: This question would be more appropriate on askubuntu.com don't you think?

Comment: I think its more universal question. Manual building is not adding *.so file